# Gridview vs Textbox vs CalendarExtender vs Updatepanel

Tags: asp.net

Buenas tardes.
Se tiene la siguiente funcionalidad con un gridview.
La grilla esta conformada por filas que son "PROCESOS" y en las columnas van "PORTAFOLIOS". La intersección o celda se coloca un checkbox para marcar si un proceso se ejecuta para un portafolio específico. Cada portafolio tiene una fecha que aplica según el proceso. Para un proceso en particular, la fecha se puede cambiar a fechas anteriores a la propuesta por el portafolio. Para ello se utiliza un calendar extender. 
Hasta ahí todo funciona correcto. La grilla se muestra bien, el calendar se despliega y si se selecciona una fecha, el textbox asociado al calendar cambia.

Pero, al hacer clic a un botón para iniciar la ejecución del o de los procesos seleccionados, el textbox de la fecha cambia y vuelve a mostrar la fecha que tenia inicialmente.

He buscado sobre el tema pero lo que encuentro no soluciona.
Por favor comentarios al respecto que puedan ayudar a solucionar este inconveniente.
Gracias de antemano

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si ya te funciona, piensa en publicar una respuesta explicando como se soluciono. Haz la respuesta como si la pregunta no fuera tuya. Puedes seguir la guia [answer] para aprender más. Un saludo

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64836/discussion-on-question-by-alejor-gridview-vs-textbox-vs-calendarextender-vs-upda).

Comment: Lo primero sería revisar los textbox asociados a los calendarExtender en cada columna de la grilla. Si está seteada la propiedad ReadOnly en true esto ocasiona que en tiempo de ejecución se mantengan los valores ya establecidos. Por lo tanto remover la propiedad ReadOnly. Si no se desea que el usuario digite sobre los textbox, se setea la propiedad Enabled = false. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396